# Jquery Message Popup Trigger and Ignoring the message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, notifications

If I want to ignore one of the notification below both of the notifications are being removed.

When the popup is triggered you should see 2 notification. The trigger has a data-badge that counts the amount of notification that are there.

If I want to ignore 1 of the notifications the data-badge should go -1 and 1 notification should be gone. When you press ignore I want to have a fadeOut on the notification. How can I do this?

```
$(function() {
    var hideDelay = 500;
    var hideTimer = null;
    // One instance that's reused to show info for the current person
    var container;
    $.get('templates/messages/popup_messages_container.php', function(data) {
        container = $(data);
        $('body').append(container);
        // Allow mouse over of details without hiding details
        $('#messagesPopupContainer').mouseover(function() {
            if (hideTimer) {
                clearTimeout(hideTimer);
            }
        }).mouseout(function() {
            if (hideTimer) {
                clearTimeout(hideTimer);
            }
            hideTimer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                container.css('display', 'none');
            }, hideDelay);
        });
    });
    $('#messagePopupTrigger').live('mouseover', function() {
        if (hideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(hideTimer);
        }
        var pos = $(this).offset();
        var width = $(this).width();
        container.css({
            left: (pos.left + width) + 'px',
            top: pos.top - 5 + 'px'
        });
        $('#messagesPopupContent').html('&nbsp;');
        var popupContent = $(this);
        var text = popupContent.attr('rel');
        $('#messagesPopupContent').html(text);
        container.css('display', 'block');
        }).live('mouseout', function() {
        if (hideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(hideTimer);
        }
        hideTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            container.css('display', 'none');
        }, hideDelay);
    });
    $("#ignore_btwnr").live("click", function(){
        var html = "<table><tr><td valign='top'><img style='padding-right:5px;' src='images/tick.png'></td><td valign='top'>Er zijn geen meldingen.</td></tr></table>";
        $('#messagesPopupContainer').remove();
        $('#messagesPopupContent').html(html);
        $('#messagePopupTrigger').removeAttr("data-badge");
        $.cookie('btwnr', '1', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        document.title = "";
    });
        $("#ignore_aangifte").live("click", function(){
        var html = "<table><tr><td valign='top'><img style='padding-right:5px;' src='images/tick.png'></td><td valign='top'>Er zijn geen meldingen.</td></tr></table>";
        $('#messagesPopupContainer').remove();
        $('#messagesPopupContent').html(html);
        $('#messagePopupTrigger').removeAttr("data-badge");
        $.cookie('aangifte', '1', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        document.title = "";
    });
    var dom_melding = $('#messagePopupTrigger').attr("data-badge");
    if (!dom_melding) {
    }
    else {
        document.title = "("+dom_melding+")";
    }
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, use `.on`